# Ruby - permutation program in one line

Tags: ruby, string, function, permutation

just started ruby :)

I am creating a small ruby program where a user inputs *a string of letters* and it prints all the possible permutations.

I am trying to write a *function that is only 1 line long*, but im having trouble getting it to run

Any help please :)

```
puts "Enter phrase:"
input_string = gets.split("")

#function
print input_string.permutation().to_a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling **[`chomp()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chomp)** before calling **[`split()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-split)**:

```
puts "Enter phrase:"
input_string = gets.chomp().split("")
print input_string.permutation().to_a, "\n"
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter phrase:
ABC
[["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C", "B"], ["B", "A", "C"], ["B", "C", "A"], ["C", "A", "B"], ["C", "B", "A"]]
```

Try it out **[here](https://replit.com/@ShashSinha1/InsecureEnchantingBlocks#main.rb)**.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can *always* write *any program* on one line, because line breaks are always optional. They can always be replaced with an expression separator (i.e. semicolon `;`), a keyword (e.g. `then`, `do`), or sometimes just whitespace (e.g. `def foo() 42 end`).

In your case, that would look like this:

```ruby
puts "Enter phrase:"; input_string = gets.split(""); print input_string.permutation().to_a
```

```
However, focusing on the number of lines is generally not a good idea as it does not necessarily increase readability. We use multiple lines in text to improve readability, so why should the same not also be true for code? Or do you think that writing this paragraph on one line has improved anything?
```

Comment: Ah, the everlasting gobstopper question: what is a "line of code?"